# How can I get struct data from hive table using JDBC?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, charts, hive

I am trying to fetch struct<> data from Hive table using JDBC via Java Swing application for jfreechart visualization. While executing SQL query it throws an `SQLException` error, it throws exception where i am getting(rs.getString("user.name")). Kindly find me a suggestion how to get struct data from hive table using JDBC application?

```
    String s1 = jTextField1.getText();
    String s2 = jTextField2.getText();
    String s3 = jTextField4.getText();
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/"+s1,"arunachalam","");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select user.name,user.followers_count c from "+s2+" order by c desc";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset( );
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String name = rs.getString("user.name");
            int count = rs.getInt("user.followers_count");
            dataset.setValue(count,name,name);
        }
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Followers Count", "Screen Name", "Users Follower Count", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
        CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();

        int width = 560;
        int height = 370;
        File bchart = new File( "Chart.jpeg" );
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG( bchart , chart , width , height );
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: Use `rs.getString(1);` instead?

Comment: thanks bro. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using like this

```
rs.getString("user.name");
```

Use this instead

```
rs.getString(1);
```

What you were trying to do earlier was to refer the column with a name along with the table name, instead use the reference/column name or you could refer it by the order in which it is used in the SELECT clause.

You could add for more columns based on the `SELECT` order. Hope this helps!